# apk (android studio) failed install

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to run an application on my android device, when I run it through android studio suddenly the application cannot be opened (even though the application can be installed). Can anyone help me solve this problem?

## ================================
MainActivity.kt

```
package com.rifqi_19104031.modul5

import android.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    // deklarasi atribut (id xml)
    private lateinit var inputProdi : EditText
    private lateinit var btnProdi : Button
    private lateinit var btnCallBrowser : Button
    private lateinit var btnCallCamera : Button
    private lateinit var inputPhoneNumber : EditText
    private lateinit var btnCallPhone : Button
    private lateinit var btnFragment : Button

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // menambahkan fungsi untuk button prodi
        btnProdi.setOnClickListener {
            val namaProdi = inputProdi.text.toString()
            if (namaProdi.isEmpty()) {
                inputProdi.error = "Prodi Tidak Boleh Kosong"
                return@setOnClickListener
            }
            val moveWithDataIntent = Intent(this@MainActivity, MainActivityReadData::class.java)
            moveWithDataIntent.putExtra(MainActivityReadData.EXTRA_PRODI, namaProdi)
            startActivity(moveWithDataIntent)
        }

        // membuka web ittp
        btnCallBrowser.setOnClickListener{
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
            intent.data = Uri.parse("http://ittelkom-pwt.ac.id/")
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        // menjalankan kamera perangkat
        btnCallCamera.setOnClickListener{
            val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        // menjalankan call phone perangkat
        btnCallPhone.setOnClickListener{
            val phoneNumber = inputPhoneNumber.getText()
            if (phoneNumber.isEmpty()) {
                inputPhoneNumber.error = "Nomor Telpon Tidak Boleh Kosong"
                return@setOnClickListener
            }
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL)
            intent.data = Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        // memanggil fungsi user permission
        setupPermissions()

        // menambahkan fungsi untuk tombol fragment
        btnFragment.setOnClickListener{
            val intent = Intent(this, Pratice5ForFragmentActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }


    // menampilkan uer permission
    val CALL_REQUEST_CODE = 100
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private fun setupPermissions() {
        val permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)
        if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE),
                CALL_REQUEST_CODE)
        }
    }
}
```

i have an error

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property btnProdi has not been initialized
```

But in my MainActivity.kt class I have initialized the btnProdi variable, is my variable declaration wrong?

Comment: Bro, read Your errors: `kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property btnProdi has not been initialized`. Seems like it'd be better for You to show the code referring the `btnProdi` variable, especially the `onCreate` method where it seems it tried to be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the error, the `btnProdi` was not initialized. To resolve the issue, first, make sure that the components in Your layout file for the `MainActivity` have their own `id`.

**activity_main.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    ...
    tools:context=".features.main.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnProdi"
        ... />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Having an `id` assigned to the `Button` in the xml file will enable us to reference the it in the kotlin code and, finally, initialize the `btnProdi`.

**MainActivity.kt**

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

   ...

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // NOTICE THIS LINE
        btnProdi == findViewById(R.id.btnProdi)

        btnProdi.setOnClickListener {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code You will use `findViewById` which will return the `View` object identified by the `id` specified before. In Your case it will be a `Button` object. From now on the `btnProdi` will be initialized and ready to use.

**Important**

In Your code there are even more buttons that lack initialization. I'm talking about `btnCallCamera`, `btnCallBrowser` etc. You should apply the same workflow as with the `btnProdi` to make sure that those buttons will work too.